# Convert code from Framework 4.0 to 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I convert some application from  Framework 4.0 to 3.5 and have problems with next code:

```
    public virtual bool TryToGetResponse(out string response, int millisecondsTimeout) {
        var mre = new System.Threading.ManualResetEventSlim(false);
        string resp = response = null;
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => {
            resp = GetResponse();
            mre.Set();
        });

        if (mre.Wait(millisecondsTimeout)) {
            response = resp;
            return true;
        } else
            return false;
    }
```

How this convert to 3.5?

Comment: What is the problem, more specifically?

Comment: ManualResetEventSlim is a 4.0 method. How to rewrite it to 3.5

Comment: Ok.But what about mre.Wait(millisecondsTimeout) ? ManualResetEvent hasn't Wait method

Comment: I think you can use `WaitOne`

Comment: Is it equivalent? Ok, i will try this

Answer (score 0):

use class `ManualResetEvent` instead class `ManualResetEventSlim`